# send mysql result to an email with php mail function

Tags: php, mysql, email

i have a php page that i used to get info from a data base , what i need is to send it in an email but for each result a new email and not all info i one same email. here is my mysql php scrtip

```
   <?php
include 'myDB.php'; 

 $sql = "this query is working perfectly ";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//var_dump($result);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "nombre del paquete: " . $row["nombre_del_paquete"]."
     <srtong>precio total:</strong> " . $row["precio_total"]. " 
    " . $row["nombre"]. "
    " . $row["apellido"]. "
    " . $row["email"]. "

    " . $row["submitted"]. "<br><br>";

        $header ="From: no-reply@test.com" . "\r\n";
    $para    = 'web2@myemail.com';
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $titulo  = 'Newsletter';

    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<img src="https://world.bookinghello.com/PromoFB/img/hello_logo.png" alt="HELLO" />';
    $message .= '<br/> <p>El siguiente usuario abandono el la compra de un paquete en booking hello </p><br/>';
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="2">';
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Nombre del paquete:</strong> </td><td>" . $row["nombre_del_paquete"]."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Nombre del paquete:</strong> </td><td>" . $row["precio_total"]."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Nombre del paquete:</strong> </td><td>" . $row["nombre"]."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Nombre del paquete:</strong> </td><td>" . $row["apellido"]."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Nombre del paquete:</strong> </td><td>" . $row["email"]."</td></tr>";

    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";



    if(mail($para, $titulo, $message, $header)){
     echo "successful";
                die();
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
}
 } else {
echo "0 results";
}


?>
```

when i remove the mail option i get 5 results in echo, when i add the mail option i only get 1 result(first one) and email is sent as well with 1 info, will like to get 5 different emails

Comment: Construct and send an email within the `while` loop, so it sends one for every record in the data?

Comment: yes i need to construct the loop and send an eamail for each record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method called `sendMail` and pass required value, which will be used when sending mail.

Then, call `sendMail` for each iteration of

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //your code
   // Call sendMail
   // some code
}
```

Comment: can you please provide me a full explination with an example of passing required values and send email, i still basic with php and mysql, thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what explanation you want, it is pretty straight forward. You need to create a method and pass value like `to`, `from` and body contents etc. Since, each iteration will have some result assuming in that iteration you will have `to` and `from` and body contents. So, same you need to pass through the method

Comment: i editted my question so you can see where i'm wrong, what is happening i only get one email witht the 1 result only and actually i have 5 results

Comment: if while loop iterating 5 times then you will receive 5 mail otherwise you won't

Comment: that is correct, i added     foreach ($row as $test) {
       $message .= $test;
  }              /////  but i keep getting 1 result only i will need 5 in this case since is 5 iteration, and yes if there is non  it doesnt sent the email

Comment: please check spam/junk, because if you are saying you are receiving single mail and while is iterating  5 times.. So, either while loop isn't iterating 5 times or you are receiving remaining mail to junk folder

Comment: the issue is this, if i remove the mail option and o echo i get all 5, when i added mail fucntion and do echo as well i'm only getting 1 iteration, the mail fucntions is working appearently, but the fecth while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) for some reason is failing when i add the mai, function